# 2sxc: What is the smart way to update an existing app?

Tags: 2sxc

just was wondering how could I update an app actually in use, so could not unistall it, so without losing data. Whats the best way? There is an automated feature for this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment there is no automatic feature for this. This is something that can never be fully automated, because an app can be changed in so many ways 2sxc could never automatically figure out how to merge.

I'll try to write a guide some time, but in general there are three quick strategies: if only the views/templates changed, just replace them. If way more changed you could export-import the content-items from "old" to "new" - or you could export/import the schemas from "new" to "old"

Comment: Hello, if I understand, so I would need to first install install the new app, export content from new and import to old. The problem is that the system will not install the new app cause name conflict so the only ways is first unistall the old one and then reinstall the new one. This in a production environment is a bit dangerous...